# SQL select and compare

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am trying to retrieve everything from client and bond table where the client.id is not equal to bond.client and bond client.bond is not equal to bond.id. My query did not work and returns the whole list instead. How can i solve this problem? My query wants to output 4 , 5 from client table and 5, 5 from bond table as the result

Client table

```
Id    Bond

1     2

2     3

4     5
```

Bond table

```
Id    Client

2   1

3   2

5   5
```

.

```
SELECT * FROM `client_table` 
 INNER JOIN `bond_table` 
where client_table.id != bond_table.client and client_table.bond != bond_table.id
```

Comment: You miss the on clause

Comment: the on clause doesn't return any result though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT c.ClientID, c.BondID from client_table c
left join bond_table b
on c.clientID = b.clientID
where b.clientID is null
UNION 
SELECT b.ClientID, b.BondID from bond_table b
left join client_table c
on c.clientID = b.clientID
where c.clientID is null
```

Answer (score 0):

could be using  not in clause

```
  SELECT * FROM `client_table` 
  INNER JOIN `bond_table` on client_table.id  
      not in  ( select bond_table.client  from bond)
          AND client_table.bond not in ( select bond_table.id from bond)
```

but based  on the resukt you show in the comment you should use OR (and not AND)

```
  SELECT * FROM `client_table` 
  INNER JOIN `bond_table` on client_table.id  
      not in  ( select bond_table.client  from bond)
          OR client_table.bond not in ( select bond_table.id from bond)
```

Comment: this unfortunately did not return any result when in fact 4,5 and 5 ,5 should be shown